# How can I open a rtsp stream with ffplay and feed the frames to opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I'm working on a CV project streaming from an IP camera. I happened to find it is faster to stream with ffplay than with opencv directly. This is because opencv does not provide a `flush()`-like function that clears the buffer before retrieving a frame. In that case, opencv always takes the first frame instead of the last frame for use.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to use ffplay (or ffmpeg) as backend to feed the latest frame to opencv.

Comparing the following code, ffplay is much faster than opencv in streaming:

```
import cv2
import subprocess


# OpenCV lags for ~1s
def cv2rtsp(rtspurl):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtspurl)
    ret, img = cap.read()

    while True:
        cap.grab()
        ret, img = cap.retrieve()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('video output', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            raise StopIteration


# FFmpeg lags for ~500ms
def ffmpeg_rtsp(rtspurl):
    command = [
        'ffplay', '-fflags', 'nobuffer', '-flags', 'low_delay', '-framedrop', '-strict', 'experimental', rtspurl
    ]

    subprocess.call(command)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rtsp = "rtsp://admin:my123456@192.168.0.53:554/h264/ch1/sub/av_stream"
    cv2rtsp(rtspurl=rtsp)
    ffmpeg_rtsp(rtspurl=rtsp)
```

Comment: You can try with `cv2.VideoCapture(ffmpeg_pipeline, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)`

Comment: is the problem constant lag no matter how long the program runs, or does your program simply read frames too slowly and they start to queue up?